# How to prevent numbering (_0, _1) of file uploads?

Tags: 7, media, files

Is there a way in Drupal 7 to prevent numbering (_0, _1) of file uploads with the same name?
How to tell Drupal to replace the previous file?
Maybe there is already a ready-made module?
Or does anyone know how to write such a module?

Comment: Maybe this module https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_replace

Comment: Is the file field created by you programmatically or via the UI?

Comment: @cilefen Via the UI